# How to Style Horizontal Line using QTextCursor

Tags: c++, qt, qtextcursor

I am trying to add a horizontal Line to the QTextCursor and change the thickness and color of the line using below code:

```
QTextDocument doc=new QTextDocument();
QTextCursor *cursor=new QTextCursor(doc);
cursor->insertHtml("<hr style='color:black;height:30px'>");
```

I am able to draw the horizontal line butthe color and the thickness of the line are not changed. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code can be used to draw a horizontal line using QTextDocument and QtextCursor:

```
QTextFrameFormat frameFormat;
frameFormat.setHeight(10);
frameFormat.setWidth(2350);
frameFormat.setBackground(Qt::black);
cursor->insertFrame(frameFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with `QTextDocument`. You may read about supported html subset in Qt [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).